# class Google_Client() is not found

Tags: php, oop, google-client

I Guess it's a common problem , a lot of similar question had been asked here but none of the solutions suggested solved the problem for me

i'm trying to use the Google Client Library in PHP but when i try to create an object from the Google_Client Class , it shows me this error : **Fatal error: Class 'Google_Client' not found**

im using : PHP v5.4 | Release v.2.4.1

notice : i'v included the autoload file, and i'm not using the composer .

any idea behind it?

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are having issues with?

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved !

i downloaded older version of the release and everything looks perfect !